# Incorrect grammar in maintenance mode message

Tags: bug, status-completed, grammar, system-message, maintenance

This message appears when Stack Overflow is in maintenance mode:

> This site is currently in read only mode, we'll return with full functionality soon.

This message has a [comma splice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_splice), meaning that a comma is being used to join two independent clauses.  To correct this, the message should read:

> This site is currently in read only mode. We'll return with full functionality soon.

Note that the comma has been replaced with a period.  This splits the message into two complete sentences.

Comment: It should also be "read-only". The comma would probably be better as a semicolon.

Comment: I think it reads perfectly fine as two separate sentences.

Comment: Hrm... someone else commented on the missing hyphen earlier. Looking for it.... EDIT: ah, it was in [a comment](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143154/site-currently-in-read-only-mode#comment406599_143158), no wonder it took so long to find. @simchona

Comment: @user1253034 I never said it *didn't* read fine as two sentences, but the semicolon is definitely a good option.

Comment: @PopularDemand: and the comment below it that says this was already fixed...

Comment: Everyone trust @simchona -- she's an English.SE mod!

Comment: They're two fine sentences, and whether to use a comma or a period is a minor nitpick at best. Fixing it serves no purpose. Is stuff like this even worth pointing out?

Comment: Agree with @Pekka, this is not about grammar but typographic conventions, and is incredibly minor at best.

Answer (score 12):

The comma is definitely wrong; it is incorrect to join independent clauses with a comma, as you point out.  But I think a semicolon would be more appropriate here, since these are closely related independent clauses.

> This site is currently in read-only mode; we'll return with full functionality soon.

Comment: [We're gonna use this one next time](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143154/site-currently-in-read-only-mode#comment406600_143158).

Comment: Awesome, @Anna - thanks!

Comment: @AnnaLear So we can fix this, but apparently the "s" key is broken on every SE keyboard in the company?

Comment: @casperOne You found us out. Every "s" in this maintenance message had to be copy/pasted from other sites.